# C# window form connecting to E62 LED Display Controller

Tags: c#, tcp

I am trying to create a C# window form for E62 LED display controller. I found the SDK of Huidu and use the demo for c# they provided. However, when i try to write the data to the controller, the program hang at the line where it send the data to the controller. This is my first time doing this project and i really need help with this. Here is the code

```
int m_nSendType;                // Send type
IntPtr m_pSendParams;           // Params

    public FormSDK()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // init send type and send params

        bool bSendUseIp = true;  

        // IP
        if (bSendUseIp)
        {
            m_nSendType = 0;
            string strParams = "192.168.2.201";
            m_pSendParams = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(strParams);
        }
        else
        {
            // Serial port see Cmd_GetBaudRate Cmd_SetBaudRate
            int nSerialPort = 4;
            int nBaudRate = 57600;
            string strParams = nSerialPort.ToString() + ":" + nBaudRate.ToString();

            m_nSendType = 1;
            m_pSendParams = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(strParams);
        }
    }

    ~FormSDK()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(m_pSendParams);
    }

    // Text
private void buttonText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr pNULL = new IntPtr(0);

    int nErrorCode = -1;
    // 1. Create a screen
    int nWidth = 64;
    int nHeight = 32;
    int nColor = 1;
    int nGray = 1;
    int nCardType = 0;

    int nRe = CSDKExport.Hd_CreateScreen(nWidth, nHeight, nColor, nGray, nCardType, pNULL, 0);
    if (nRe != 0)
    {
        nErrorCode = CSDKExport.Hd_GetSDKLastError();
        return;
    }

    // 2. Add program to screen
    int nProgramID = CSDKExport.Hd_AddProgram(pNULL, 0, 0, pNULL, 0);
    if (nProgramID == -1)
    {
        nErrorCode = CSDKExport.Hd_GetSDKLastError();
        return;
    }

    int nX = 0;
    int nY = 0;
    int nAreaWidth = 64;
    int nAreaHeight = 32;

    // 3. Add Area to program
    int nAreaID = CSDKExport.Hd_AddArea(nProgramID, nX, nY, nAreaWidth, nAreaHeight, pNULL, 0, 0, pNULL, 0);
    if (nAreaID == -1)
    {
        nErrorCode = CSDKExport.Hd_GetSDKLastError();
       return;
    }

    // 4.Add text AreaItem to Area
    IntPtr pText = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("12345");
    IntPtr pFontName = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("Arial");
    int nTextColor = CSDKExport.Hd_GetColor(255, 0, 0);
    int nAreaItemID = CSDKExport.Hd_AddSimpleTextAreaItem(nAreaID, pText, nTextColor, 0, 4, pFontName, 16, 0, 30, 201, 3, pNULL, 0);
    if (nAreaItemID == -1)
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pText);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pFontName);
        nErrorCode = CSDKExport.Hd_GetSDKLastError();
        return;
    }
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pText);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pFontName);

    // 5. Send to device 
    nRe = CSDKExport.Hd_SendScreen(m_nSendType, m_pSendParams, pNULL, pNULL, 0);
    if (nRe != 0)
    {
        nErrorCode = CSDKExport.Hd_GetSDKLastError();
    }
}
```

This is the demo that the developer provided. The program hang at the line "nRe = CSDKExport.Hd_SendScreen(m_nSendType, m_pSendParams, pNULL, pNULL, 0);". Is it because the parameter are not correct? And also i want to know does each controller has its IP number? I can't find the IP number of the controller even in the manual.

Are there any further configuration needed besides the code they provide in the demo to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Search for "huidu hd2020 software", download and install it. This is the official software from manufacturer. In Settings->Device Manage you should be able to find your controller. Set an IP address. It's a little tricky here. Before clicking OK, click Settings button. Now your controller should have an IP. Keep your bSendUseIp variable true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have to properly set up a network adapter settings.

After you connect to your controller via Huidu magic using HD2020, you will be able to setup custom IP and gateway settings on your controller. (Default for HD-E63 is 192.168.2.200 with gateway 192.168.2.1) When you have done it, or magic didn't work go to the ethernet connections settings on your machine and set your ip to a different one but in the same subnetwork, 192.168.2.100 with gateway 192.168.2.1 will work. (default port for communicating with controllers is 6101, UDP)

Use Wireshark to trace packets on your connection if any problem arises. I am currently developing with this SDK, ask any questions if anyone have.